# Finding the shortest path in the maze, SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, maze

How can I find the shortest way in (for example) this maze (on clearly SQL, without using PL/SQL functions):

Start point: 's', end point: 'e'

```
'00   000  e000000'  
'         0       '
'0000 000 0 00000 '
'   0   0   0     '
's0 000 000 00000 '
' 0               '
```

As a result, there should be something like this

```
'00   000  e000000'  
'         0-      '
'0000 000 0-00000 '
'---0   0  -0     '
's0-000 000-00000 '
' 0---------      '
```

I'm not waiting for a ready solution in SQL code, but I have no idea how it's solved in SQL. Can anyone knows any algorithms? Target database Oracle.

Comment: SQL was designed primarily to manage data in RDBMS and not for networking rules,graphs and solving mazes etc..

Comment: I know it, but I must solve this task in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches

1. Brute force using recursive subquery factoring.
2. Lee algorithm using model clause + iterations.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm

**Update. Quick demonstration of first approach.**

```
column str format a30
with t(y, str) as
(         select 1, '00   000  e000000' from dual
union all select 2, '         0       ' from dual
union all select 3, '0000 000 0 00000 ' from dual
union all select 4, '   0   0   0     ' from dual
union all select 5, 's0 000 000 00000 ' from dual
union all select 6, ' 0               ' from dual)
, matrix as
(select x, y, str, substr(str, x, 1) z, rownum id
from t
cross join (select rownum x from dual connect by level <= 17))
, rec(x,y,z,id_list) as
(select x, y, z, cast(id as varchar2(4000)) from matrix where z = 's'
union all
select m.x, m.y, m.z, r.id_list || '|' || m.id
from matrix m
join rec r on (r.x + 1 = m.x and r.y = m.y
           or r.x - 1 = m.x and r.y = m.y
           or r.x = m.x and r.y + 1 = m.y
           or r.x = m.x and r.y - 1 = m.y)
          and instr('|' || r.id_list || '|', '|' || m.id || '|') = 0
          and m.z != '0'
          and r.z = any ('s', ' ')
)
, route as
(select regexp_substr(x, '\d+', 1, rownum) mark
from
(select max(id_list) keep 
        (dense_rank first order by regexp_count(id_list,'|')) x
from rec
where z = 'e')
connect by level <= regexp_count(x,'|'))
select y, listagg(decode(z, ' ', nvl2(mark, '=', z), z))
          within group (order by x) str
from matrix
left join route on id = mark
group by y
order by y;

         Y STR                           
---------- ------------------------------
         1 00   000  e000000             
         2          0=                   
         3 0000 000 0=00000              
         4 ===0   0  =0                  
         5 s0=000 000=00000              
         6  0=========                   

6 rows selected.
```

Model solution is much more efficient but SQL is not the best way to solve this specific task anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for ideas:

1. Reachability queries are not expressible in "plain" SQL SELECT statements, unless...
2. Recursive Common Table Expressions (WITH clause) can make a SQL SELECT statement Turing-complete.